# I am facing an error with codeigniter pop modal with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have two fields which one is province and another is district which are:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Province *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">                
        <select id="province" name="province" class="form-control selectboxit" onchange="get_districts(this.value)" required="">    
            <option value="">Select Province</option>           
            <?php
            $province = $this->db->get('provinces')->result_array();
            foreach ($province as $row):
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $row['provinceID']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['province_name']; ?>
                </option>                                
                <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>          
        </select>
    </div>                
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">District *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
        <select id="district" name="district" class="form-control" >
            <option value="" selected="selected">First Select Province</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_districts(val) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/get_district/' + val,
            success: function (response)
            {

                jQuery('#district').html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function valida(val) {
        if (val == "Rent") {
            document.getElementById("rent_amount").disabled = false;
        }
        if (val == "Personal") {
            document.getElementById("rent_amount").disabled = true;
        }
    }

</script>
```

It works fine for me in views pages but when I am working these things in pop modal it's not working by clicking this link the pop up modal shows up with data but the ajax isn't working:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_branche_edit/<?php echo $row['branch_id']; ?>');">          
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>    
</a>
```

The pop up modal is working fine but the ajax is not working.
Please any suggestion?

Comment: Where is this function defined `showAjaxModal`?

Comment: function get_district($prvoince_id) {
        
        $district = $this->db->get_where('districts' , array('provinceID'=>$prvoince_id))->result_array();
        echo '<option> Select District</option>';
        foreach ($district as $row) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['districtID'] . '">' . $row['district_name'] . '</option>';
        }
    }

Comment: where is `showAjaxModal`?

Comment: the pop modal is going to displayed by clicking this link but i want to click on the province so onChange method doesn't display the district filed

Comment: the show AjaxModal function is in my 'views/backend'  in modal.php

Comment: You can not call a php controller function `showAjaxModal` with onclick. It will try to find the function in JavaScript code.

Comment: while the modal page which i am displaying is with showAjaxModal is in 'views/backend/admin/modal_baranch_edit.php'